# Duplicate index on separate dom elements jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, indexing

I have the following html structure

```
<div class="someClass">
    <button class="actionButton" id="b0"></button>
</div>
<div class="otherClass">
    <button class="actionButton" id="b1"></button>
    <button class="actionButton" id="b2"></button>
    <button class="actionButton" id="b3"></button>
    <button class="actionButton" id="b4"></button>
</div>
```

I use a function to deactivate the buttons based on their index in the dom using the actionButton class as the selector like so

```
function DisableButtons(indexes, disable) {
    $('.actionButton').each(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        alert($this[0].id + " index: " + $this.index());
    });
}
```

My alert shows the following output

```
b0 index: 3
b1 index: 0
b2 index: 1
b3 index: 2
b4 index: 3
```

The button in the first div wrapper has the same index as the last button in the second div wrapper.  Is this a markup issue?

Seeing how the buttons in the second div block return correctly i can only assume the issue is markup/selector related.  How can i remedy this issue without changing my markup?

Comment: Use the index passed to the .each callback, or strip it off the ID. jQuery collections are always in DOM order unless using `.prevUntil` or `.sort`

Comment: [I just tried and got the expected result](http://jsbin.com/esupev/1/edit) (open the console). Can you reproduce your problem in a fiddle ?

Comment: I'm getting the correct values. Could you create a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I see 00123 at your jsbin @dystroy, i assumed the expected result was 01234

Comment: @KevinB That's not how I understood OP's question. But I'm not sure as this wasn't explicit.

Comment: The index is relative to the parent. 00123 is what I received and expected as well.

Comment: There's something you're not showing us, and I'm assuming it probably has to do with creating unintended globals. This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qcbuS/ shows your exact code, but not your exact results.

Comment: That or `<div class="someClass">` contains more elements than shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
$this.index()
```

try

```
$('.actionButton').index($this)
```

Using the index method this way will [Search for a given element from among the matched elements.](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/LJnDX/)**

You want to get the index of the button based on all the buttons with `class="actionButton"` .

Comment: @opdb.. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 2):

> If we omit the argument, .index() will return the position of the
>   first element within the set of matched elements in relation to its
>   siblings

- http://api.jquery.com/index/

Try this -

`$('.actionButton').index($this)` instead of `$this.index()`

Output :

```
b0 index: 0 
b1 index: 1 
b2 index: 2 
b3 index: 3 
b4 index: 4
```

Demo `-->` http://jsbin.com/esupev/2

Comment: perfect, thank you.  I must have skimmed right past that line in the reference.

Comment: @opdb - I do believe Sushanth gave the same answer five minutes earlier.

Comment: @adeneo7 indeed, i didnt look at the answered time.